# Linking two YAML files

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, yaml

I'm currently trying to link two YAML file in Flutter.
The problem is that one of the YAML file (for example `amount.yaml`)is there for keeping the values in order (index) and the other one (for example `fruit_specification.yaml`) is for specifying the first YAML file.

Here is the example:

first YAML file **fruit_specification.yaml**:

```
fruit: 
    - name: apple
      color: red
      amount: 3
    - name: banana 
      color: yellow
      amount: 2
    - name: plum 
      color: purple 
      amount: 5
```

and the second YAML file that I'm trying to link  to have a navigation in Flutter **amount.yaml**:

```
- amount: 2
- amount: 3
- amount: 5
```

Now how can I combine these two YAML files in Flutter so I can use the order from the `amount.yaml` file while accessing the values from `fruit_specification.yaml`.

Comment: why are you using YAML file to store the data?

Comment: to make the program more flexible. I'm making a bluetooth App to configure our hardware and for that I need to store the values in a YAML file to make it more accessible. The values are characteristics form that bluetooth hardware and the values need to be changeable.

Comment: and also i would really like it when i can use Listview.builder for this issue.